# Material Table - unable to properly implement

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I'm trying to use mat table like in the example `Table retrieving data through HTTP` from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">
  <!-- firstname Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vorname</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.firstname}}</td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

```js
export class AccessManagerComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['firstname'];
  data: Observable<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private backendService: BackendService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.data = this.sort.sortChange.pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.backendService.getUsers(this.sort.active, this.sort.direction)
      }),
      tap(console.log),
      map(response => response.items)
    )
  }
}
```

It is working however i'm getting the error `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.` because `sort` is only initialized after the view has initialized.

`sort` is not getting initialized as long as the table is not rendered but once the table is rendered i'll get this error cause it'll trigger a new fetch (as it should).

I'm able to get around this issue if i'll subscribe inside the component and set `data` there but it would be nice to find a solution which allows me to use the observable as a datasource for the mat table.

Comment: https://indepth.dev/posts/1053/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular

Comment: there's an article with a video about this error in the Angular documentation, they give a few hints about fixing that. See https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: I know what this error is about but i don't know how to properly implement this using given example. If you take the example from the angular docs and just directly bind the observable as table datasource you'll get this error. Subscribing in the component is discouraged afaik because you'll have to manually unsubscibe

Comment: `this.sort.active` and `this.sort.direction` will be always the same on component initialisation, so you can get that info based on your columns (for `this.sort.active`)